# Is there a way to cath HTTP 429 errors (Too Many Requests) at a dynamic web page resources level?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dynamic web page (standard html/css/javascript) that is serverd by an nginx reverse proxy, which enforces some strict rate limits.
All good here, as the page works as expeced, up until the rate limits are hit, at which point nginx will stop serving resourced for the defined period of time, returning 429 errors instead. Which is what I want, but at this point the frontend web page, will be cought in different stages of being loaged: either css, js or image files might end up not being loaded at all. Requireing a page refresh, after the rate limit period was reset by nginx.

So the question is, how can I detect any 429 errors (at css, js or image files) at the web page level, so that I can properly report an alert on the page, so that users know what to do?

I can intercept some of these errors at ajax calls levels, but so far I was not able to detect them at the page images , js scripts and css files loading levels.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: `script` and `link` elements have `onerror` handlers as well. Apart form that, maybe use the [resource timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceResourceTiming)

Comment: onerror doesn't return error details. Is just a bucket for all possible errors. So not very useful for my case